# Get Transparent PNG in Browser to another application without saving or losing tansparency

Tags: browser, png, clip

Suppose I am on Win7, and am using any modern browser, and on the web page I am looking at there is a PNG with transparency, and I want to get it into another App, say Photoshop or Fireworks or the Clipboard; and I want the transparency NOT to turn Black.

The only way I've found to do this is by `right-click,save image`, then dragging that image into the app, or onto the apps canvas.

If I do `right-click,copy image` and paste it into app, I get black transparency. The same if I drag the image from the webpage, even if the 'webpage' is the image url.

Where is the problem here: browser, clipboard or what.

So far I've tried Chrome, SeaMonkey, Firefox, and Slimboat.
And here I thought I was living in the 21st century.

Is there an add-on?

I found [Copying PNG with transparency from browser shows a black background instead](https://superuser.com/questions/237784/copying-png-with-transparency-from-browser-shows-a-black-background-instead) on Superuser. Is this the definitive answer, if so I can't believe it.